# How should I do an efficiency analysis of an AC motor driver in LtSpice?

Tags: analog, simulation, power-electronics, ltspice, induction-motor

I have two different AC motor drivers and I need to test them for energy efficiency in an analysis tool (I know only LtSpice).

But I don't know how to model an AC motor. Driver's circuitries are given. They are 3-phase AC motor drivers. Can you tell me how should I model an AC motor and how to do an efficiency analysis in LtSpice?

Answer (score 1):

I don't hink you can,  definitely not in ltspice. Efficiency is Pout/Pin, but it depends on motor working point (velocity, acceleration, losses) , which you have to define. If you have a switching driver, it's even more complex,since power wasted on the driver almost doesn't depend on the motor, just on the current.

Comment: If I monitor the current drawing from the supply I can calculate the total energy dissipation which is the exact thing I need. I just need to compare two AC motor driver, one will be used as reference. I see this guy ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtD-M-PhkvQ ) uses a model, I am trying to find it in LtSpice and in LinearTechnology but I could not. If I use identical motors and configure the drivers to have the same frequency and (coil) current amplitude why would it not be a good comparison?